# Open CV histogram equalized graph built-in function

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, histogram

I know OpenCV's cvEqualizeHist function and have the histogram equalized image. Is there any built-in function to have equalized histogram (graph). For example I am going to give histogram graph as an argument to the function and it will generate equalized histogram graph?

Comment: It's hard to understand exaclty what you need, but I'm pretty sure the answer is: "no, no builtin function"

Comment: Hi Miki! I actually wrote a code that displays equalized histogram and and resulting equalized color image. I checked equalized color image's correction with open cv's equalizeHist function. However, I could not check its corresponding equalized histogram. That's why I was searching a built in function to assure if my code displays correctly. @ Miki

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32079157/5008845)?