# Display the histogram of the horizontal and vertical projections of the image opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram, projection

I have got the horizontal and vertical projections of the image of a silhouette{Mat shape}.  I would like to display it as a histogram . I tried normalizing and drawing with the line function But couldn't. Please help . Thanks in advance .[silhouette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCzO1.png)

```
Mat ret;
threshold(shape,ret,0,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV+CV_THRESH_OTSU);
Mat horizontal(ret.cols,1,CV_32S);//horizontal histogram
horizontal = Scalar::all(0);
Mat vertical(ret.rows,1,CV_32S);//vertical histogram
vertical = Scalar::all(0);
for(int i=0;i<ret.cols;i++)
{
    horizontal.at<int>(i,0)=countNonZero(ret(Rect(i,0,1,ret.rows)));
}
for(int i=0;i<ret.rows;i++)
{
   vertical.at<int>(i,0) = countNonZero(ret(Rect(0,i,ret.cols,1)));
}
normalize(vertical,vertical,0,ret.rows,NORM_MINMAX);
```

Comment: Probably can [help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32079157/5008845)